# What's the reason for getting "Could not execute statement; org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException" when i use just Crud Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

What could be the reason for getting
"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkd98071syj0prd7flivawss6f]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"?
but I just used deleteById(businessLine) an CRUD REPOSITORY method.

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/businessLine/{businessLine}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteBusinessLine(@PathVariable("businessLine") Long businessLine) {
        return lobAgendaService.delete(businessLine);
    }

public ResponseEntity<?> delete(Long businessLine) {
        lobAgendaBusinessLineRepo.deleteById(businessLine);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new CommonResponse("deleted Succesfully", null));
    }
```

When a delete option is clicked for a particular running note, it has to be deleted. Instead I'm getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXO2I.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means there is a relationship between BusinessLine and some class.
If you want to delete with the child datas you can add this.

```
@OneToMany(...
           orphanRemoval = true
           ...)
private List<T> ...;
```

Warning!!!
You would lose important data by mistake somehow if you add `orphanRemoval = true` in it !!

Or else you could delete the children before you delete parent data in business logic layer.